# Android Listview with LinkedHashMap does not add the list row after calling notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, adapter, baseadapter

I am developing a application where we want to display the custom list view which display the list of running application with their transmit and received data usage.

I have used the `LinkedHashMap` data structure for android list view's adapter and calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on same adapter whenever running application has change the data usage it will reflect in list view.

Upto this it is working fine but when new application starts transmitting or receiving  data, this application will not add into list view.

Here are code snippet:

**`Adapter : ProcessListAdapterWithMap`**

```
public class ProcessListAdapterWithMap extends BaseAdapter {

// List context
private final Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long>();
private Integer[] mKeys;


public ProcessListAdapterWithMap(Context context, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long> data) {
    this.context = context; 
    this.linkedHashMap = data;

    mKeys = linkedHashMap.keySet().toArray(new Integer[data.size()]);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
}

/**
 * Constructing list element view
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder; // to reference the child views for later actions        

    if (rowView == null) {

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.process_view_list_row, parent, false);

        // cache view fields into the holder
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.appName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        holder.text_upload = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.upload_data);
        holder.text_download = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.download_data);
        holder.appIcon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        // associate the holder with the view for later lookup
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }else{

        // view already exists, get the holder instance from the view
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag(); 
        rowView = convertView;
    }   

    Logger.vLog("ProcessListAdapterWithMap :-> getView", "mKeys Length : "+mKeys.length);

    int app_uid = mKeys[position];

    ProcessInfo processInfo = new ProcessInfo().getApplicationDetailFromUID(this.context, app_uid);

    holder.appName.setText(processInfo.getApp_name());

    long actual_transmit = (processInfo.getApp_transmit());
    holder.text_upload.setText(""+actual_transmit);

    long actual_receive = (processInfo.getApp_receive());       
    holder.text_download.setText(""+actual_receive);

    holder.appIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(processInfo.getApp_icon());

    return rowView;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return linkedHashMap.size();
}

@Override
public ProcessInfo getItem(int position) {

    int app_uid = mKeys[position];
    ProcessInfo processInfo = new ProcessInfo().getApplicationDetailFromUID(context, app_uid);

    return processInfo;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

class ViewHolder {

    TextView appName;
    TextView text_upload;
    TextView text_download;     
    ImageView appIcon;

}
}
```

**`Generating a List view and assigned a adapter to it`** -

```
    processList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.process_list);
    lhmOfAppsWithDataUsage = getLinkedHashMapFormSet(setOfRunningAppUID);

    listAdapterWithMap = new ProcessListAdapterWithMap(DataCollectionScreenActivity.this, lhmOfAppsWithDataUsage);
```

**`apply notifyDataSetChanged() method`** :

```
printMap(DataCollectionScreenActivity.this, lhmOfAppsWithDataUsage);                
Logger.vLog("Runnable : ", "LinkedHashMap Size : "+lhmOfAppsWithDataUsage.size());                              

listAdapterWithMap.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**`UPDATE :`**

I have get correct application list in the log. but it will not replicate into the list view.

Where is the problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't you need to process `mKeys` again every time the map changes?

Comment: Yes @Ken we need. As we processed on the key of the HashMap so this will be required.

Comment: But you are not doing so... so this is the problem I think? It's only processed the first time you create the adapter. You need a new method call in your adapter before you call `notifydatasetchanged()` to repopulate the keys. Otherwise you will get no data.